# About the android scale animation xml

Tags: android, xml, animation, scale

I am going to make the vibrating animation when click the image in xml.
But the scale animation not work as I expect.
The size is too large when animating.
Here is my ani_zooming.xml

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="300" />
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="2.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.6"
    android:toYScale="1.6"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.6"
    android:fromYScale="1.6"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="900"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.25"
    android:toYScale="1.25"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1200"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.25"
    android:fromYScale="1.25"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1500"
    android:duration="300" />
```

This is code in java:
     public void onImageClick(View view)
     {
        Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.ani_zooming);
        view.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use relative values for the scale values, not absolute values.
Please use following code in your ani_zooming.xml.

```
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="300" />
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.6"
    android:toYScale="1.6"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.625"
    android:toYScale="0.625"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="900"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.25"
    android:toYScale="1.25"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1200"
    android:duration="300" />

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:toYScale="0.8"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1500"
    android:duration="300" />
```

Replace the values for the fromXScale, fromYScale, toXScale, toXScale when zoom out.